# Cognos filter to last fiscal week

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

We're self learning cognos 11 currently and trying to work out how to use an advanced filter for last fiscal week. We run Sunday-Saturday and would want to always show last week no matter what day we run the report on

Comment: Since Cognos has functions that often map directly to SQL functions, so I always start with, "How would I do this in SQL?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that I am not actually doing someone's homework.  You can try the following expression:

```
    [Date]> _add_days(current_date,-_day_of_week(current_date,7)) and [Date]<=
_add_days(_add_days(current_date,-_day_of_week(current_date,7)),7)
```

Comment: It's definitely been over 10 years since I last had homework. Our company is a bit slow on sorting out training. Anyway, this has worked great for current fiscal week, how can I amend this to get the previous fiscal week?

Comment: All good!  Always glad to help. Instead of going back 7 days try going back 14 as per the below

  [Date]> _add_days(current_date,-_day_of_week(current_date,14)) and [Date]<=
_add_days(_add_days(current_date,-_day_of_week(current_date,14)),7)